# SQL Query to get three closest locations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Here's my query conundrum:
 - I have a table of customers with the longitude and latitude for their
   zip code. 
 - I have a table of suppliers also with longitude and
   latitude for their zip code. 
 - There are no relationships between the
   tables.
 - I have a User Defined Function that calculates the distance
   between two sets of longitude and latitude.

I have the following query that can show (up to) the three closest suppliers within a 50 mile radius for a given customer (dbo.latlngdistance is the user defined function):

```
select top 3 dname1, dcity, dstate, dzip, dbo.latlngdistance(dlr.latitude, dlr.longitude, 
    (select lat from homeowner where ho_identifier = 16), 
    (select lng from homeowner where ho_identifier = 16)) AS SortDistance
from dlr
where dbo.latlngdistance(dlr.latitude, dlr.longitude, 
    (select lat from homeowner ho_identifier = 16), 
    (select lng from homeowner where ho_identifier = 16)) between 0 and 50
Order By SortDistance
```

I have another query that returns all the suppliers within a 50 mile radius of all customers (I have limited the number of customers in this example because performance for this query is horrible):

```
select ho.ho_identifier, ho.ho_firstname, ho.ho_lastname, ho.ho_email, dname1, dcity, dstate, dzip
from dlr
    cross join homeowner ho
where dbo.latlngdistance(dlr.latitude, dlr.longitude, 
    (select lat from homeowner ho2 where ho.ho_identifier = ho2.ho_identifier), 
    (select lng from homeowner ho3 where ho.ho_identifier = ho3.ho_identifier)) between 0 and 50
and ho.ho_identifier in (16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
Order By ho.ho_identifier
```

So my question is how do I get (up to) the three closest suppliers within a 50 mile radius for **all** of the customers?

Comment: try make another user-defined function or store procedure to do your first query in a loop?

Comment: I should have mentioned I am stuck on SQL Server 2000 -- I know, right?

Comment: that sucks, there is way of making it by using multiple joins but i do not think that way is a good way...

Comment: If you can upgrade the database to something made within the last decade you can use a spatial data type, which has builtin support for determining k-nearest neighbors (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/isaac/archive/2008/10/23/nearest-neighbors.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what a former co-worker suggested:

I think I would try to collect the target homeowners into a temporary table to keep things contained, and then use SQL to step through each one step through each one procedurally.

such as (mind you I can't test any of this)

```
Select HO_Identifier, zip.lat, zip.lng INTO MyTempHO
From DBC_Homeowner
LEFT Join Zip on zip.zip = left(5,HO_Zip) AND Zip.ll = 'L'  //I think there might also be a function to get lat/lng from zip....
WHERE <Your homeowner selection criteria>
```

That should give you a smaller table to work with.  Check that all the Lat, Lng fields were filled in, there might be a problem with the zips on some.  Of course Left(5 only works for USA, not canada)

Create another table to hold the results, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE MyResults (HO_Identifier int,DLR_Identifier int)
```

The write a loop to go through each row and find the top 3 dealers, such as

//run all this as one statement

```
Declare @HO_Identifier int, @HO_Lat double, @HO_Lng double

Declare Cursor HO from select HO_Identifier , Lat, Lang from MyTempHO

OPEN HO
FETCH FROM HO Into @HO_Identifier, @HO_Lat, @HO_Lng 
While @@INDEX = 0
BEGIN
    Insert MyResults (@HO_Identifier, Dlr.dlr_Identifier) Select TOP 3 DLR_Identifier from dlr 
        where dbo.LAtLngDistance(@HO_Lat, @HO_Lng, dlr.lat, dlr.lng) < 100
        AND <Your other dlr criteria>
        AND dlr.lng between HO_Lng + <some negative amount to limit results> AND HO_Lng - <Same negative amount> //Note lng is negative!
        ORDER BY dbo.LAtLngDistance(@HO_Lat, @HO_Lng, dlr.lat, dlr.lng)

    FETCH NEXT FROM HO Into @HO_Identifier, @HO_Lat, @HO_Lng 
END

CLOSE HO
DEALLOCATE HO
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a view with a definition similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    ho.ho_identifier, dlr.dname1, --dlr.id would be even better, but you didnt give the name of the id column
    dbo.latlngdistance(dlr.latitute, dlr.longtitude, ho.lat, ho.lng) AS distance
FROM dlr d
CROSS JOIN homeowner ho
```

Given that this view will be called calculatedDistances you could then find the closest suplier with something like:

```
SELECT ho.ho_identifier, dlr.dname1
FROM homeowner ho
JOIN calculatedDistances dis
    ON dis.ho_identifier = ho.ho_identifier
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM calculatedDistances nearer
        WHERE
            nearer.distance < dis.distance
            AND nearer.ho_identifier = ho.ho_identifier
    )
```

Finding three closest would be more tricky and could involve some serious performance issues. You could do something like:

```
SELECT 
    dis.ho_identifier, dis.dname1
FROM calculatedDistances dis
LEFT JOIN calculatedDistances nearer
    ON nearer.ho_identifier = dis.ho_identifier
    AND nearer.distance < dis.distance
GROUP BY dis.ho_identifier, dis.dname1
HAVING ISNULL(COUNT(1), 0) < 3
```

Once again - you may need to store the calcutedDistance in some other tables if you are having performance issues.

It is now quite late where I live so sorry if I made any mistakes. If so, please comment this answer and I will try to correct myself tommorow.

Comment: The view you suggest creates a Cartesian join, which given the size of the tables I'm dealing with (+50,000 suppliers and +26,000 homeowners) creates serious performance issues (e.g. I killed the query using a single ho_identifier after two minutes). But I like the direction you are going!

And BTW, I do have a dlr_identifier column.

Comment: Thats the issues I have been writing about. On the other hand - you should have very similar execution plans with your queries. Perhaps you could create a table that would hold the calculated results of the function?

Comment: Well I constrained the view to distances between 0 and 50 miles, which helped for the single ho_identifier query, but querying 5 ho_identifiers is taking over three minutes so far. BTW, I'm using the last query to suggested for finding the three closest.

Comment: One other thing that could help improve performance would be to rewrite the view to not use the scalar function, but to do the calculations inline. Helpfull reading: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3845381/T-SQL-Best-Practices-150-Don146t-Use-Scalar-Value-Functions-in-Column-List-or-WHERE-Clauses.htm